# How can we read/display the data to be inserted in HSQLDB programmatically before data being written to disk?

Tags: java, database, desktop-application, hsqldb

I am running two instances of my java based desktop application on same HSQLDB database. I am trying to operate in such a way that when record is inserted from one instance it should be immediately reflected/displayed in another instance of application. But the issue is HSQL keeps data in temporary memory area and writes the data to disk after database is closed/shutdown. I just want to know,is it possible what i am trying ? or how one can implement this functionality ?
Thank You.

Comment: Can't you refresh your data display on both app instances continuously (for example every 2 minutes)?

Comment: @ra2085 Thank you for your reply. I have committed data after every transaction and re-executing the select query each time i open that particular JFrame in apps but still it is not showing data.

Comment: Can you confirm that the data has been commited by means of the HSQL Database Manager? In short, can you query your data outside of your app scope?

Comment: I'm guessing you're not using the in-app embedded mode of HSQLDB...

Comment: Yes you guessed right,i am not using HSQLDB in embedded mode.I didn't tried querying my database from outside of application.Is there any way to refresh/autorefresh the database after each operation or anything else ?

Comment: Why would you need to refresh the database? Doesn't make sense. The database must keep data and transaction integrity, no need to do that manually/programatically. Give a try to query the database outside the application and let me know the results.